# Overlapping footnotes on title page

Tags: footnotes, titles, footmisc, titling

When I try to use `footmisc` and `titling` packages in a document, there are a problem with author footnote marks. Footnote marks overlap in a single point. Here my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\thanksmarkseries{arabic}
\title{Title}
\author{Author \thanks{A}\thanks{B} \and Author\thanks{C}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello everyone
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

See footnote marks 1 and 2. How I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to insert a fake footnote-sized `1`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\thanksmarkseries{arabic}
\title{Title}
\author{Author\thanks{A}\protect\phantom{\footnotesize 1}\textsuperscript{,}\thanks{B} 
  \and 
  Author\thanks{C}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello everyone

\end{document}
```

You can decide whether or not to keep the separating `\textsuperscript{,}`.