# Single foot note without altering or overlapping page number

Tags: footnotes

I have a very simple question, how can I create a foot note for a single page of the document without overlapping the page number, like in the picture:

\\

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that, sometimes the code would overlap them when using certain footing packages, I am sure some people had similar problem before.

Comment: Ah, like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349241/overlapping-footnotes-on-title-page?s=1|45.7349, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260607/footnotes-overlapping-with-page-number?s=3|40.3788.  Those were specific to particular packages or document classes.

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to write `\footnote{...}` just next to the word I wanted to clarify something about.